# terraform module source variable

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

in my terraform code, i'm calling my module this way (main.tf) :

```
module "gitlab_group_creation" {
  source                    = var.module_source
}
```

my variables file contains this :

```
variable "module_source" {
  type    = string
}
```

I'm using gitlab CI to init/plan/deploy via terraform.
I created a variable in gitlab CI called TF_VAR_module_source, it's value is the git link to my module.

however, when running terraform init with gitlabCI, i have this error :

```
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│ On main.tf line 19: Variables may not be used here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsuitable value type
│ 
│ On main.tf line 19: Unsuitable value: value must be known
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid module source address
│
```

Apparently module source doesn't accept a variable as input. Is there any way to make the source referencing a variable ?

Comment: Show us line 19 of `main.tf`

Comment: source  = var.module_source

Comment: Is module `gitlab_tools_group_creation_tools` open source? What outputs does it have?

Comment: no it's the name of my module, the module creates a gitlab group and outputs it's id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using one module local variable in another module in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042096/using-one-module-local-variable-in-another-module-in-terraform)

Comment: not really, i want source to reference a variable. That variable should be the path a terraform project in gitlab that creates ressource. I can reference it using a string source = "....git" but when it comes to reference it as var, i have an error that indicates that │ Error: Variables not allowed for that source parameter. I'm trying to figure out a workaround

Comment: See https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4424813474963-Unsuitable-value-value-must-be-known-error-the-module-definition-section

Comment: Terraform doesn't allow variables for module source. The module source has to be available during the `init` phase, and Terraform doesn't evaluate variables during the `init` phase.

Answer (score 0):

Module installation is done only by `terraform init`, and input variables are a plan-time idea so the modules must have already been installed by that point. Like most language ecosystems, Terraform does not allow dynamically installing new dependencies at runtime.